# How to create result for different shared parameters in TFS using API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, msdn, azure-devops

I have some steps in my test case. Now a step has few shared parameters which creates different iterations while running manually through TFS. How can i fetch these parameters and acheive the same through code using TFS API

Comment: please provide more details of your requirement. I understand it as you want to fetch parameters via API (if so, please check my reply below). Do you also want to set values to these shared parameters? And also run test cases via API?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response..Yes i want to set the values and then run all the remaining steps for each and every parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the parameters in test step, run the code below:

```
 TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
        ITestManagementTeamProject project = tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>().GetTeamProject("teamproject");

        ITestCase testcase24 = project.TestCases.Find(24); //24 is the test case id

        foreach (System.Data.DataTable dataTable in testcase24.Data.Tables)
        {
            string header = "";
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn colume in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                header += colume.ColumnName + "\t";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(header);
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                string rowValue = "";
                foreach (object o in row.ItemArray)
                {

                    rowValue += o.ToString() + "\t";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(rowValue);
            }
        }
```